# No sound card detected

Tags: 16.04, soundcard

I am using Ubuntu 16.4 dual booted with window 10. Earlier Ubuntu was working fine but recently no audio is coming, it is not showing no sound card. In window 10 everything is working fine. I have tried almost everything available on web but nothing works.

Edit:

```
hwinfo --sound
```

o/p

```
 16: PCI 1f.3: 0403 Audio device                                 
 [Created at pci.366]
 Unique ID: nS1_.5pt2u8hjfCD
 SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
 SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
 Hardware Class: sound
 Model: "Intel Audio device"
 Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
 Device: pci 0x9d71 
 SubVendor: pci 0x17aa "Lenovo"
 SubDevice: pci 0x382c 
 Revision: 0x21
 Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
 Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
 Memory Range: 0xb1320000-0xb1323fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
 Memory Range: 0xb1310000-0xb131ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
 IRQ: 129 (no events)
 Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00009D71sv000017AAsd0000382Cbc04sc03i00"
 Driver Info #0:
 Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
 Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
 Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

Comment: Please add the output of the following command  `hwinfo --sound` to your post.

Comment: @abu_bua i have edited my question. Ty

Comment: your sound card seems to be ok.  I think you have a notebook, so only one sound card. Please also post the  output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`. Then try `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav ` and if you don't hear something try `sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav ` . Your lenovo should has special function keys where you can *mute* the sound, try it and also prove in the system menu (upper right corner) that the voulme is not set to mute.

Comment: Update : Now my sound card is visible in the sound setting, but still sound is not coming. my Ubuntu is taking more time in boot up and some time cursor is also not visible, and about sound i didn't do anything this morning when i turned it on and checked card was available. i have already reinstalled Ubuntu once.

Answer (score 0):

Try the check on the ubuntu page the [troubling sound-nosound](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en).

[Debugging Sound Problems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems) from the ubuntu wiki is also a very good reference.

Since you have the **SndHdaIntel** sound chip try this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SndHdaIntelSoundProblems) .